# Download opions shown to call script

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I'm using jsf with Primefaces when I press commandButton for download xls.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{stud.downloadAction} value="Download"/>
```

My doubt is When I press commandButton browser export option shown that option show (browser download option shown script listener can call the function) time to I need to call script?

```
function testScript()
{
alert(message);
}
```

Comment: *"My doubt is"*: is your doubt correct? If so, are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I'm not getting any error.My doubt is Download excel file from specific folder.When export option shown time need call specify function script?Is this Possible?